# Running a script in multiple tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I would like to run the following scripts in all my tabs on google sheets (Not just Jan 2021), any ideas?

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  //1.Change 'Sheet1' to be matching your sheet name
  if (r.getColumn() < 9 && ss.getName()=='Jan 2021') { // 2. If Edit is done in any column before 
Column (I)  And sheet name is Sheet1 then:
var celladdress ='A'+ r.getRowIndex() 
ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  }
};
```

Comment: @Ruben the post you used to close this question as a duplicate might have the same title as this one, but the solution is way different than what the OP asked for.

Comment: The Mogsdad's answer start explaining  how to use the event object... that is core of any solution fot this question. By the other hand the OP didn't included any info about their search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask] and we already have a lot of similar questions.

Comment: @Rubén how is the event object the core of the question? Both me and the OP didn't use it .

Comment: @Marios actually you are using it... onEdit(e)

Comment: @Rubén I am defining it as a function parameter but I don't use it anywhere. Anyway, if you feel that way you have the right to close it :) It is indeed a post related to many posts, but I am not convinced with the post used as duplicate.

Comment: @Marios Do you have a suggestion of a better canonical question?

Comment: @Rubén *"...the OP didn't included any info about their..."* As a majority of the questions here. Should all of them be closed?

Comment: @marikamitsos If they are duplicate, yes.

Comment: @Rubén Oh please.... No comments :/

Comment: @marikamitsos Have you read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1595451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 - predifined list of sheet names:**

One solution would be to **predefine** the sheet names of the sheets you want the `onEdit` function to apply to and use [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check whether the active sheet is one of them:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  var sheetNames = ['Sheet1','Jan 2021','Feb 2021']; 

  if (r.getColumn() < 9 && sheetNames.includes(ss.getName()) ) { 
var celladdress ='A'+ r.getRowIndex() 
ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  }
};
```

Please adjust `['Sheet1','Jan 2021','Feb 2021']` to your own list of names.

---

**Solution 2 - all sheets:**

If you want the `onEdit` function to be executed for all the sheets then simply remove the sheet name from the `if` condition:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();

  if (r.getColumn() < 9 ) { 
var celladdress ='A'+ r.getRowIndex() 
ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  }
};
```

---

**Solution 3 - run to all sheets excluding some:**

It is based on the logic of the 1st solution. You use `!includes` to **exclude** a predifined list of sheets you don't want to be part of the `onEdit` function:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  var sheetNamesExclude = ['Sheet2','Jun 2021','Aug 2021']; 

  if (r.getColumn() < 9 && !sheetNamesExclude.includes(ss.getName()) ) { 
var celladdress ='A'+ r.getRowIndex() 
ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  }
};
```

Comment: Great answer. It is a shame it is marked as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! Hopefully I will be able to help someone else out in the future as I build up some knowledge